# Using For To VB. Net to read 10 Column Database in SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, listbox

I have a program to read 10 columns from a table in a SQL Server database and store them into a listbox. I know how to read one column and store it into a listbox like this :

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
con.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT K0 FROM tbl_inven WHERE Serial = '3320'"), con)
Dim myreader As SqlDataReader

myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
myreader.Read()

If myreader.HasRows Then
     ListBox1.Items.Add(myreader("K0"))
End If

con.Close()
```

How to read 10 columns and store them into the listbox?

I just know SQL query to read 10 columns:

```
SELECT K0, K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9 
FROM tbl_inven 
WHERE Serial = '3320'
```

Can it be used to read the 10 columns? I already try to make the code using For TO but get error

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("SELECT K'"&i&"' FROM tbl_inven WHERE Serial = '3320'"), con)
        Dim myreader As SqlDataReader
        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        If myreader.HasRows Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(myreader(""))
        End If
        con.Close()
    Next
```

Anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: You only need to change your `cmd` `SqlCommand` to mimic what you have in SQL query. Better still to use parameterized query.

Comment: i don't understand sir

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code you are making 100 Sql queries... the first will translate as `SELECT K'0' FROM tbl_inven WHERE Serial = '3200'` Note the K'0'

If you want 10 columns then do the following

```
Dim SqlStr as String
SqlStr = "SELECT "
For x = 0 to 8
    SqlStr += "K" & x & ", "
Next
SqlStr += ", K9 FROM tbl_inven WHERE Serial = '3200'"

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=RF_World;Integrated Security=True"
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlStr, con)
      ....
    con.Close()
```

Comment: Ok... what are you trying to add to the list? The error is showing that there is no value for K because you do not have K you have K0, K1, K2... K9.

Comment: i try to read data from column K0, K1, K2, K3 ... K9 and add to Listbox